# Does virus VBS Jenxcus affect Linux operating system?

Tags: malware

Recently I connected to my linux a pendrive infected with VBS Jenxcus. Did it affect my operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its coded in VBScript and affects only PCs running Windows distributions.